# Which one is more desired when dealing with dates? sql DateTime or nvarchar string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Does SQLs built-in `DateTime` type has any merits over `nvarchar` type?

If it were you , which one would you use?

I need to store dates in my SQLServer database and I'm curious to know which one is better and why it is better.

I also want to know what happens if I for example store dates as string literals (I mean `nvarchar` )? Does it take longer to be searched? Or they are the same in terms of performance ?

And for the last question. How can I send a date from my c# application to the sql field of tye `DateTime`? Is it any different from the c#s DateTime ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're given a `date` datetype for a reason, why would you *not* use it?

What happens when you store "3/2/2012" in a text field?  Is it March 2nd?  Is it February 3rd?

Store the date in a `date` or `datetime` field, and do any formatting of the date after the fact.

**EDIT**

If you have to store dates like `1391/7/1`, your choices are:

- Assuming you're using SQL Server 2008 or greater, use the `datetime2` data type; it allows dates earlier than 1753/01/01 (which is what `datetime` stops at).
- Assuming you're using SQL Server 2005 or earlier, store the dates as Roman calendar dates, and then in your application, use date/time functions to convert the date and time to the Farsi calendar.

Comment: There are more than just one DateTime in sql,which one should i use?I also intend to store the dates in Farsi (dotnet framework 4 supports it)I want to face any hassles in the future though.

Comment: why do you need to store the dates in farsi.. a date represents date, the culture is insignificant, your presentation layer should deal with showing the date in the correct culture

Comment: The dates in Farsi Start within 1300 to probably 1400 while in english we have 1900 up to 2050 for example.Suppose i need to store a date like (1391/7/1 as in (yyyy/mm/dd) ) will this be simply saved ? what about date validation?

Comment: Thanks,but Date2 adds a time as well,Can i somehow omit the time part?

Answer (score 2):

Use the correct datatype (`date/datetime/datetime2` dependant on version and requirement for time component).

Advantages are more compact storage than storing as a string (especially `nvarchar` as this is double byte). Built in validation against invalid dates such as 30 February. Sorts correctly. Avoids the need to cast it back to the correct datatype anyway when using date functions on it.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm storing a DateTime value, and I expect to perform date-based calculcations based on it, I'll use a DateTime.

Storing Dates as strings (varchars) introduces a variety of logistical issues, not the least of which is rendering the date in a proper format. Again, that bows in favor of DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the DateTime since you can use various functions on it directly.
string wouldn't be too much of a hassle but you will have to cast the data each time you want to do something with it.

There is no real performance variance while searching on both type of fields so going with DateTime is better than strings when working with date values.

Answer (score 1):

you must realise the datetime datatype like other datatypes is provided for a reason and you should use the datatype that represents your data clearly.. Besides this you gain all the functionalities/operations that are special to the datetime datatype..

One of the biggest gains is correct sorting of data which will not be possible directly if you use nvarchar as your datatype.. Even if you think you dont need sorting right now there will be a time in the future where this will be useful.

Also date validation is something that you will benefit from. There is no confusion of the dateformat stored i.e dd/mm or mm/dd etc..

Answer (score 1):

There is lot discussed about the subject. There is good post on the SQLCentral forum about this particular subject  [DateTime or nvarchar](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1136418-1292-1.aspx).

In short, nvarchar is twice as longer as datetime, so it takes more space and on the long range, any action affecting it will be slower. You will have some validation issues and many more.